# Websphere MQ 7.5.0.2 Intermittent errors receiving messages in XA Transaction

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, distributed-transactions

The sample program below is supposed to be started periodically and should process all messages on a queue (on another machine) as fast as possible and then stop.  Each message should be processed in a separate distributed transaction as the processing will also need to access and alter multiple databases.

The Managed mode seems to be too slow as it processes 1 message every 3 seconds.

The Unmanaged mode has acceptable performance but I'm having 2 problems with that.

1) When the program ends, the event log of the server contains hundreds of error messages, all reporting the same error:

```
28/01/2014 15:20:49 - Process(8604.48) User(<<username>>) Program(amqrmppa.exe) Host(<<server machinename>>) Installation(Server) VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(<<queuemanager name>>)

Error on receive from host <<client machinename>> (<<client ip>>).  

An error occurred receiving data from <<client machinename>> (<<client ip>>) over TCP/IP. This may be due to a communications failure.  

The return code from the TCP/IP recv() call was 10054 (X'2746'). Record these values and tell the systems administrator.
```

2) Running the program against a queue with a limited number of messages goes fine (except for the problem above), but but after processing a few hundreds of messages (500+) it suddenly crashes with the following exception:
`MQException: MQRC_UOW_ENLISTMENT_ERROR, CompCode 2, Reason: 2354`

The second problem is probably related to the first, but I don't see anything wrong with the code.  All MQ objects are properly disconnected, closed and disposed.

All help is welcome...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Transactions;
using IBM.WMQ;

namespace WMQTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string HostName = "TST010";
        private const int Port = 5021;
        private const string ChannelName = "CL_QMSTST010";
        private const string QueueManagerName = "QMSTST010";
        private const string QueueName = "SD.TRANSX.ARCHIVE";

        private static readonly MQGetMessageOptions GetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions
        {
            Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT,
            WaitInterval = 20000
        };

        private static readonly TransactionOptions TransactionOptions = new TransactionOptions { Timeout = TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout, IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable };

        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Use managed mode?");
                var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                bool managedMode = key.KeyChar == 'y' || key.KeyChar == 'Y';
                var properties = new Hashtable
                    {
                        {MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, HostName},
                        {MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, Port},
                        {MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ChannelName},
                        {
                            MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,
                            managedMode ? MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED : MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT
                        }
                    };
                while (true)
                {
                    //starting a transaction scope            
                    using (var transaction = managedMode
                                                 ? new TransactionScope()
                                                 : new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                                                        TransactionOptions,
                                                                        EnterpriseServicesInteropOption.Full))
                    {
                        using (var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, properties))
                        {
                            using (
                                MQQueue queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName,
                                                                         MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF +
                                                                         MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING))
                            {
                                var message = new MQMessage();
                                try
                                {
                                    queue.Get(message, GetMessageOptions);
                                }
                                catch (MQException ex)
                                {
                                    if (ex.CompCode != 2 || ex.ReasonCode != MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)
                                    {
                                        throw;
                                    }
                                    //No message available, stop
                                    break;
                                }
                                //TODO: DO SOME INTERESTING DATABASE STUFF HERE
                                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message.MessageId));
                                //
                                message.ClearMessage();
                                queue.Close();
                            }
                            queueManager.Disconnect();
                        }
                        transaction.Complete();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION OCCURRED");
                Console.WriteLine("==================");
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few fixes available in the XA area. These are all for Managed mode. You may want to contact IBM to get these fixes and apply and see if that helps.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IC92296

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IC92931

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IC92932

Comment: Thanks.  We already created a PMR for similar problems with XMS.NET.  We'll see what comes out of that...

Comment: I just tested the program above against the v7.5 Fixpack 3 that was recently released.  That has all the fixes you mention embedded.  Unmanaged mode still has the described problems.  Managed mode seems to run OK, but still leaves 1 error in the event log of the WMQ server after each run.